# How to connect to different Databases(sqlserver) from Windows Service in C#

Tags: c#, windows, service

My Windows service should connect to different Databases and get the data from that (multitenent). and each connection maintain in seperate thread.  Is this possible?

Database information is available in XML file.

Does anyone have a suggestion about how this can be done?

Comment: C#, VB or what? Needs more info. Also, what are you trying to achieve? There are lots of ways to approach this vague goal.

Comment: @alphadogg see the title it is C#

Answer (score 0):

Windows services run all of the time and as you have the database details contained within a config file of sorts then you can read the connection string from there.

When structuring the code, a service is no different from a console program, other than those bits necessary for the ServiceManager to pick up on.

So structure the code such that the main logic is database agnostic i.e. it doesn't care whats beyond the datalayer interface only that it knows what the interface is.

Check out Repository and factory patterns. These will be of help. You can then create a concrete instance of the correct database class at runtime, by reading what the config file says.

Remember that the service will always run (unless set to be manually triggered) and have it be able to fail quietly if it doesn't find the config file.